# release event.data.ptr when epoll_ctl(del) a fd

Tags: events, epoll

I use event.data.ptr to point to an object.
When I epoll_ctl(del) the event I have to delete the object(pointed by event.data.ptr). 
How can I get the pointer? 
epll_ctl(del) just ignores the parameter 'event':

int epoll_ctl(int epfd, int op, int fd, struct epoll_event *event);

Do I have to maintain a vector of these objects? I think its a little dirty.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it is in fact. There is no way to query the data field in the epoll interface. The common workaround is to keep that data in your own list in user-space.

I think its time someone write an epoll syscall to query that field to avoid duplicated data associated to a file descriptor.

Comment: It has been 8 years, and no such syscall I can find does this. Gosh.

Comment: Note that, even if you can query the `event.data.ptr` field before `epoll_ctl(del)`. If some other thread close the fd, and causing fd to be removed from epoll, you will still get memory leak.